# What is the tangent cone of the set of low-rank positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, positive-semidefinite

Consider a subset of the set of all $n$-by-$n$ symmetric real matrices, as defined below

$$S := \{ M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \mid \mbox{rank}(M) \leq r, M \succeq 0 \}$$

Given a matrix $M \in S$, what is the Bouligand and Clarke tangent cone of $S$ at $M$? Equivalently speaking, what is $T_S(M)$ for a $M \in S$?

---

Below are two papers that answers two related questions:

- [The tangent cone of the set of low-rank matrices](http://num.math.uni-goettingen.de/%7Er.luke/publications/HosseiniLukeUschmajew17.pdf)
- [The tangent cone of the set of positive semidefinite matrices](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10957-011-9980-6)

Comment: Do you agree with my edits? Please include full references, for links can be broken. Have you taken a look at [Optimization Algorithms on Matrix Manifolds](https://press.princeton.edu/absil)?